# How to grep the word within the (...) using shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I want to grep the next to my search word and write in to the same file. I know how to search and add a new word write in to the same file using Shell script. but i don't know how to grep the word

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE =$1

if[-f $LOGFILE ];
then
sed -i 's/Apple /& Samsung /g' myfile.txt
else 
echo "$LOGFILE not found "
fi
```

But i want to know how to grep the next word and write again with in a print statement.

Example
here i want to grep the word next to sqrt word. I want to grep the contain in with the ( ).

```
collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 4D0*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt(lambda)**) collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 15*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt(eds)**) collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 4D444444440*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt(2*4 wq)**).
```

Expected

```
collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 4D0*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt(lambda) *print(lambda)***) collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 15*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt(eds) *print(eds)***) collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 4D444444440*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt(2*4 wq) *print(2*4 wq)***).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be a way:

```
sed -i.bak 's/sqrt(\(\w*\))/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g' file
```

Which will update the file to:

```
collisionf2.F90: temp_cons = 4D0*sml_pi/(lambda*sqrt(lambda) print(lambda)) collisionf2.F90: temp_cons = 15*sml_pi/(lambda*sqrt(eds) print(eds)) collisionf2.F90: temp_cons = 4D444444440*sml_pi/(lambda*sqrt(2*4 wq)).
```

- `sed 's/something/new/g'` is the basic command to replace all "something" with "new".
- `sed -i` does -inplace- edit. This way the original file is replaced with the new output. Doing `sed -i.bak` the original file is saved as `file.bak`.
- `sqrt(\(\w*\))` matches `sqrt(` plus something plus `)`.
- `sqrt(\1) print(\1)` prints back `sqrt(` plus that "something" plus `)` plus `print("something")`.

With a more basic input file:

```
$ cat a
lambda(sqrt(hello)) blabla
$ sed 's/sqrt(\(\w*\))/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g' a
lambda(sqrt(hello) print(hello)) blabla
```

---

All together:

```
#!/bin/bash 

LOGFILE=$1 

if [ -f $LOGFILE ]
then 
        sed -i.bak 's/sqrt(\(\w*\))/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g' $LOGFILE
else 
        echo "$LOGFILE not found " 
fi
```

Comment: What error do you get, @vkmss1986? Is the second example working to you?

Comment: Ah, right, for this you just have to add `-i`. See my updated answer.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

LOGFILE =$1

if[-f $LOGFILE ];
then
 sed -i 's/sqrt(\(\w*\))/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g' a
 myfile.txt
else 
echo "$LOGFILE not found "
fi

Comment: @vkmss1986 update your question with this code. In comments it is hard to distinguish.

Comment: this my code. Im unable to  add print(..) in my file. No change in my myfile.txt

Comment: You are using `if[-f $LOGFILE ]`, which needs a extra space after `[` ---> `if[ -f $LOGFILE ]`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42592/discussion-between-vkmss1986-and-fedorqui)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/\((.*?)\)/)' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> echo "abc(def)"|perl -lne 'print $1 if(/\((.*?)\)/)'
def
```